# "Benutzer" vs. "Nutzer" vs. "Anwender"

Tags: difference, noun

What's the difference between these terms?

According to the wikipedia entry for [Benutzer](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benutzer) clarifies it for me a little bit (but it doesn't address "Nutzer"):

> **Benutzer** sind Personen oder Personengruppen, die sich zur Wahrnehmung ihrer Aufgaben einer Datenverarbeitungsanlage bedienen und [… dabei] in unmittelbarem Kontakt mit der Anlage stehen.
>
> **Anwender** sind Organisationen oder Institutionen, die die Anschaffung und den Betrieb der Anlage oder Software verantworten (Auswahl, Lizenz, Installation).
>
> Im Duden lautet der eintrag: „Ein Unternehmen, das für die Verwaltung eines Lagers eine Rechenanlage einsetzt, ist ein Anwender. Die mit der Bedienung des Lagerhaltungsprogramms beauftragten Lagerarbeiter sind Benutzer.“

Also, Google Translate doesn't seem to be consistent when choosing an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ich würde den Unterschied zwischen *Nutzer*, *Benutzer* und *Anwender* nicht auf der semantischen Ebene suchen. Also nicht: Was ist der Bedeutungsunterschied? Ich denke, der Hauptunterschied zwischen diesen drei Wörtern liegt - wie in der deutschen Sprache so oft - in den Verwendungszusammenhängen (ist also ein pragmatischer, kein semantischer).

Es gibt für jedes dieses drei - semantisch weitgehend deckungsgleichen - Wörter verschiedene Nutzungszusammenhänge, in denen es *üblich* (geworden) ist, eines davon den anderen vorzuziehen.

Man könnte von einer ususmäßigen Assoziation der Wörter und Kontexte sprechen.

> Der Benutzer der Schreibmaschine [nicht: Anwender, Nutzer]
>
> Der Anwender des Textverarbeitungsprogramms [eher selten: Benutzer]
>
> Der Nutzer des Textverarbeitungsprogramms
>
> Der Benutzer des öffentlichen Nahverkehrs [nicht: Anwender]

Und so weiter. Zum Lernen hilft nichts weiter als diese Assoziationen mit der Zeit aufzufassen und zu verinnerlichen.

Übrigens: Es gibt auch noch den *Nutznießer*.

> Die Nutznießer der Steuerreform verschieben ihr Geld jetzt in Aktien.

Jedoch würde man nicht von *Nutznießern eines Tabellenkalkulationsprogramms oder einer Schreibmaschine* sprechen. Was *Nutznießer* gegenüber *Nutzern* auszeichnet, ist, dass sie den Nutzen oder den Genuß einer Sache ohne eigenes Zutun haben, während *Nutzer, Anwender* und *Benützer* ein bestimmtes Maß an eigener Aktivität an den Tag legen, um die Nutzung zu bewerkstelligen.

Comment: Shouldn't the answer be in the same language as the question?

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf  Usually yes. On the other hand, Gerardo quotes quite complex definitions in German, so I suppose he understands German well. Moreover, as a user of the French language sister page, I am always annoyed when topics of French language are discussed in English, not in French. I visit the site because I want to improve my French... I suppose that people who come here have a similar interest in German. But I admit that according to the set of rules in use here you are right.

Comment: Warum genau eigentlich nicht "Nutzer einer Schreibmaschine"?

Comment: @tofro  Die Frage nach dem "Warum" lässt sich meines Erachtens nicht beantworten. Es hat sich halt so durchgesetzt. Manche Linguisten würden vielleicht von einem *invisible hand*-Phänomen sprechen. - Oder wolltest du sagen, dass für Dein Sprachgefühl "Nutzer einer Schreibmaschine" eine übliche (unauffällige, normale, reguläre, unüberraschende) Sprachverwendung wäre? Das kann ja durchaus sein. Ich kann nur auf Grundlage meines eigenen Sprachgefühls hier urteilen.

Comment: Yep, genau das wollte ich sagen.

Comment: @tofro   Dann sind wir wohl in unterschiedlichen Sprachbenutzerkreisen aufgewachsen.

Answer (score 6):

The three terms are almost 100% synonyms regarding IT. Between *Nutzer* and *Benutzer* I don't see any difference: They both stand for users of an app, device or anything else (machine, service, etc.). They are completely interchangeable.

Only *Anwender* is slightly different. 
It might stand for a user of an app same as the former two. 
But usually means someone who works with the complete IT- system.

In a company the *Anwender* would be all the people working for the company with IT equipment. *Benutzer* / *Nutzer* usually are people working with a specific software or aspect of the software (e.g. network drives).

As a small example: The *Anwender* works with his (Windows-) notebook, the *Nutzer* uses Microsoft Office when working on his notebook.

Comment: The difference between *nutzen* and *benutzen* is extremely subtle. One could say *Ich nutze das Angebot.* – *I take the offer.* but **not** *Ich benutze das Angebot.* – *I use the offer.* So, you are a *Nutzer* in that case, and not a *Benutzer*.

Answer (score 1):

Ein Nutzer erlangt beim Nutzen von etwas einen Nutzen. Es ist also gewinnbringend oder bereichernd für ihn. Hingegen benutzt ein Benutzer etwas ohne einen Nutzen daraus zu erlangen. Das kommt einer Anwendung von etwas gleich (Anwender).

Comment: Tatsächlich macht *Benutzer* keine Aussage über einen Nutzen, er kann aber durchaus vorhanden sein.

Answer (score 0):

As the quote is related in IT, I share my field of IT (software development), which has usually this distinction:

- Anwender: the person interacting with/using the software
- Benutzer: a person (entry) in the database/list of users.
- Nutzer: see *Benutzer*

That is done to make statements such as "Der Anwender berechtigt den Benutzer x auf den Ordner y." and still have it clear that *Benutzer* is only a used object/artifact.

Yet this distinction is by far not carved in stone - the aim is only that anyone involved knows who or what is meant. So any usage would fit as long as it is *precise and used consistently*.

Which implies that there is no stringent pattern that has 99+% approval by native speakers.

So for use "in the public" I direct to the other answers.